# How to pass comma-separated list as value to l3keys in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, latex3, xparse

I would like to do the following:

```
\mycmd{foo={a,b,c},baz={1,2,3}}
```

where `{a,b,c}` and `{1,2,3}` are arrays/sequences of data.

The MWE is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}

\keys_define:nn { mycmd }
{
  \foo .tl_set:N = \l_mycmd_foo_tl,
  \baz .tl_set:N = \l_mycmd_baz_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand\mycmd{m}{
  \keys_set:nn { mycmd } { #1 }

  % iterate through `\l_mycmd_foo_tl` comma-separated list
  % iterate through `\l_mycmd_bar_tl` comma-separated list
}

\mycmd{foo={a,b,c},baz={1,2,3}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither `foo` nor `baz` are key names

Comment: And what should the iteration do?

Comment: The iteration should just `\typeout` the value that's fine. In my case each iteration impl would be something custom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If comma separated lists are mandatory, use `foo .clist_set:N` etc. in order to set `expl3` clists and than iterate over them, e.g. with `\clist_map_inline:Nn`, where `##1` is replaced with the relevant entry of the list (assuming that `\clist_map_inline:Nn` is used within another macro).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn



\begin{document}

\keys_define:nn { mycmd }
{
%  \foo .tl_set:N = \l_mycmd_foo_tl,
%  \baz .tl_set:N = \l_mycmd_baz_tl

  foo .clist_set:N = \l_mycmd_foo_clist,
  baz .clist_set:N = \l_mycmd_baz_clist
}

\NewDocumentCommand\mycmd{m}{
  \keys_set:nn { mycmd } { #1 }

  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_mycmd_foo_clist {
    value\space##1\par
  }

  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_mycmd_baz_clist {
    value\space##1\par
  }

  % iterate through `\l_mycmd_foo_tl` comma-separated list
  % iterate through `\l_mycmd_bar_tl` comma-separated list
}

\mycmd{foo={a,b,c},baz={1,2,3}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: “If comma separated lists are mandatory,” kind of reads as though it is implying “this is not the usual or best way to do this, but if you absolutely must do it this way due to constraints outside your control...” If that’s the case, it might be worth describing briefly at the end of the answer what the more typical/better approach to this would be. (If that’s not the case, it may be worth rewording.)

Comment: @KRyan: No, I don't meant it that way. If the O.P. wants to have comma separated lists (i.e. he/she imposes this requirement) then `\clist` is the best way.