# key={v,a,l} argument separated by commas in xparse

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expl3, xparse, l3keys

I'm trying to create a command to show the distributive property of multiplication (for school effects) using `tikzmarks` and `xparse`. So far so good, the code is a bit long and I would like to know if I can accomplish this in a more summarized way (the right way ...my code is not very neat).

The subject is like this, I have defined a command `\tikzmkpd[...]{...}{...}` which receives an optional argument `[key=val]` and two mandatory arguments separated by commas. With the mandatory arguments it works perfect, the problem I have when trying to implement `[key=val]`. My idea is that `[key=val]`works like this:

```
config-A={yshift={#1},end-yshift={#1,#2,#3},color={#1,#2,#3},distance={#1,#2,#3}}, 
config-B={yshift={#1},end-yshift={#1,#2,#3},color={#1,#2,#3},distance={#1,#2,#3}}
```

For now of `config-A` I only have written the `yshift` and `end-yshift` keys that control the spaces of the beginning and end of the arrows that I am drawing with `tikz`.

My problem is with the key `end-yshift={#1,#2,#3}` which calls the command auxiliary `\endyshift{...}`. By using the command `\endyshift{...}` directly it accepts:

```
\endyshift{#1}
\endyshift{#1,#2}
\endyshift{#1,#2,#3}
```

but if I use it in `[key=val]` it becomes obligatory to pass the three parameters:

```
end-yshift={#1}       % error
end-yshift={#1,#2}    % error
end-yshift={#1,#2,#3} % correct
```

I've tried `{}` or `,`, ` as "empty" arguments, but it doesn't work, besides, I think the code is pretty long and maybe it can be achieved using another strategy.

Here's my question then, can you pass `key={v,a,l}` where `v`, `a` and `l` execute different code?

This is my example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz,etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,calc,tikzmark}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example
\pagestyle{empty}
% short :)
\newcommand*{\TkM}[2]{\tikzmarknode{#1}{#2}}
% active : for expl3
\makeatletter
\def\@colon{:}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd }
 {
  config-A  .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A } { #1 } },
 }
% config-A={yshift={#1},end-yshift={#1,#2,#3},color={#1,#2,#3},distance={#1,#2,#3}}
\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A }
 {
  yshift     .dim_set:N = \l_yshift_A_dim,
  yshift     .initial:n = 1.7ex,
  yshift-AC  .dim_set:N = \l_yshift_AC_dim,
  yshift-AC  .initial:n = 1.7ex,
  yshift-AD  .dim_set:N = \l_yshift_AD_dim,
  yshift-AD  .initial:n = 1.7ex,
  yshift-AE  .dim_set:N = \l_yshift_AE_dim,
  yshift-AE  .initial:n = 1.7ex,
  distan-AC  .dim_set:N = \l_distance_AC_dim,
  distan-AC  .initial:n = 1.00ex,
  distan-AD  .dim_set:N = \l_distance_AD_dim,
  distan-AD  .initial:n = 2.00ex,
  distan-AE  .dim_set:N = \l_distance_AE_dim,
  distan-AE  .initial:n = 3.00ex,
  colour-AC  .tl_set:N  = \l_color_AC_tl,
  colour-AC  .initial:n = red,
  colour-AD  .tl_set:N  = \l_color_AD_tl,
  colour-AD  .initial:n = green,
  colour-AE  .tl_set:N  = \l_color_AE_tl,
  colour-AE  .initial:n = blue,
  end-yshift .code:n    = \endyshift{#1},
%  yshiftall  .meta:n    = {end-yshift={#1}, yshift = #1,}, % not work
 }

\NewDocumentCommand { \endyshift } { m }
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \clist_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    {1}{\EndACshift {#1}} %
    {2}{\EndADshift {#1}} %
    {3}{\EndAEshift {#1}} %
   }{}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \EndACshift }{m}
 {
  \EndAC#1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \EndAC #1 
 {
  \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A } 
   { 
    yshift-AC = #1,
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \EndADshift }{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}
 {
  \EndAD#1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \EndAD #1 #2
 {
  \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A } 
   {
   yshift-AC = #1,  
   yshift-AD = #2,
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\EndAEshift}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}
 {
  \EndAE#1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \EndAE #1 #2 #3
 {
  \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A } 
   { 
    yshift-AC = #1, 
    yshift-AD = #2,
    yshift-AE = #3,
   }
 }

% case 1: a(c+d)  A1(B1+B2)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_case_one:n
 {
  \draw[->,color=\l_color_AC_tl] ([yshift=\l_yshift_A_dim]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A1})$) 
   to[out=60,in=120,distance=\l_distance_AC_dim] 
   ([yshift=\l_yshift_AC_dim]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B1})$);
  \draw[->,,color=\l_color_AD_tl] ([yshift=\l_yshift_A_dim]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A1})$) 
   to[out=60,in=120,distance=\l_distance_AD_dim] 
   ([yshift=\l_yshift_AD_dim]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B2})$);
 }
% case 2: a(c+d+e) A1(B1+B2+B3)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_case_two:n
 {
  \_case_one:n
  \draw[->,color=\l_color_AE_tl] ([yshift=\l_yshift_A_dim]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A1})$) 
   to[out=60,in=120,distance=\l_distance_AE_dim] 
   ([yshift=\l_yshift_AE_dim]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B3})$);
 }
% case 3: (a+b)(c+d) (A1+A2)(B1+B2)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_case_tree:n
 {
  \_case_one:n
  \draw[->] ([yshift=-0.5ex]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A2})$) 
   to[out=-60,in=-120,distance=1ex] ([yshift=-0.5ex]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B1})$);
  \draw[->] ([yshift=-0.5ex]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A2})$) 
   to[out=-60,in=-120,distance=2ex] ([yshift=-0.5ex]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B2})$);
 }
% case 4: (a+b)(c+d+e) (A1+A2)(B1+B2+B3)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_case_fourth:n 
 {
  \_case_tree:n
  \draw[->,color=\l_color_AE_tl] ([yshift=1.7ex]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A1})$) 
   to[out=60,in=120,distance=3.0ex] ([yshift=1.7ex]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B3})$);
  \draw[->] ([yshift=-0.5ex]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A2})$) 
   to[out=-60,in=-120,distance=3ex] ([yshift=-0.5ex]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B3})$);
 }
% user command
\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzmkpd}{O{} m m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \IfNoValueF { #1 } { \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd }{ #1 } }
   \foreach \x [count=\n] in {#2} { \csxdef{A\n}{\x} }%  save in A<n>
   \foreach \y [count=\m] in {#3} { \csxdef{B\m}{\y} }%  save in B<m>
   \tikzset{>={Straight ~ Barb[length=1.5pt,round,bend]}}%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember ~ picture]%
    \bool_if:nTF { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #2 } = 1 }   && 
                   \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #3 } = 2 } } { \_case_one:n }{  }
    \bool_if:nTF { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #2 } = 1 }   && 
                   \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #3 } = 3 } } { \_case_two:n }{  }
    \bool_if:nTF { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #2 } = 2 }   && 
                   \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #3 } = 2 } } { \_case_tree:n }{  }
    \bool_if:nTF { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #2 } = 2 }   && 
                   \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #3 } = 3 } } { \_case_fourth:n }{  }
   \end{tikzpicture} 
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{case 1}

$\TkM{A}{2a^2}(\TkM{B}{b}+\TkM{D}{3q})$%
\tikzmkpd[config-A={end-yshift={2ex,2ex,2ex}}]{A}{B,D}

\section{case 2}

$\TkM{a1}{2p}\left(\TkM{b1}{3q}+\TkM{c1}{4r}+\TkM{d1}{1}\right)$
\tikzmkpd{a1}{b1, c1, d1}

\section{case 3}

$(\TkM{X1}{2a^2}+\TkM{X2}{n})(\TkM{Y1}{b}+\TkM{Y2}{3q})$%
\tikzmkpd{X1,X2}{Y1,Y2}

\section{case 4}

$(\TkM{a}{x}-\TkM{b}{2})(\TkM{c}{x^2}+\TkM{d}{2x}+\TkM{e}{4})$
\tikzmkpd{a,b}{c, d, e}

\end{document}
```

And an example of the output that produces:

[image: output that produces]

Any help is appreciated.

PS: The idea of the command is NOT to write the `tikzpicture` environment directly into the document.

Comment: As far as I understand, the all that TikZ code isn't really relevant to the problem. Could you boil down the example to only the code that is necessary to understand the parameter parsing problem?

Comment: You can probably pass whatever you need as `key={some,thing}` by defining `key` with `l3keys`' `.code:n` or `.tl_set:N`, but then for the passed-in contents, you'll have to do the parsing work yourself (unless you delegate to `l3keys` again...). Wouldn't it be more natural to use hierarchical keys in the style `mykey/mysubkey=...` (see *Sub-dividing keys* in the `l3keys` documentation)?

Comment: Unlike the others I feel you should drop `xparse` and `etoolbox`. That way you avoid mixing pgf keys with other keys. Of course, I do not fully understand what's going on here but the splitting of the arguments can be achieved with the `/.list` key handler.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reduce the example code, I think the question would be misunderstood (writing using `expl3` is always extensive). Going straight to `pgfkeys` is not an option for me, I don't know it well and it would cause me more problems (I'm new to `tikz`), subdividing the keys seems a good idea to me, I'll try.

Comment: Reviewing well in the forum I found the answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423119/7832) , to the moderators I ask to leave this question as closed (duplicate)