# Problem passing a key=color (separated by commas) from l3keys to tikz

Tags: macros, expl3, l3keys

After a good time searching the forum I gave up (I thought I could do it by myself), I have a problem passing a key from `l3keys` (separated by commas) to `tikz`. 
I've created a command that accepts comma-separated arguments and `key=val` that encapsulates `tikz(mark)` to generate school examples like these:

[image: output]

The command is as follows

```
\tikzmkpd[config-A={yshift-A={#1}, end-yshift={#1,#2,#3},
                    color={#1,#2,#3}, yshift-A={#1}, distance={#1,#2,#3}
                    angle-star={#1,#2,#3}, angle-end={#1,#2,#3},
                    }]{A,B}{C,D,E}
```

Keys that accept arguments separated by comma are all passed through the same function and everything works OK, with the exception of `color` key, when activated I get the error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `gray' (in 'gray').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.126 ...,yshift-A=15pt,color={gray,red}}]{A}{B,D}
```

The function does not delimit it correctly and absorbs more than the account, passing the rest of the arguments to `tikz`, the strange thing is that if I define the same code within `\keys_define:nn` it works correctly:

```
\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A }
 {
  color .code:n = {
                   \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #1 }
                   \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #1 } = 1 } }
                    {
                     \tl_set:Nx \l_colour_AC_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
                    }
                   \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #1 } = 2 } }
                    {
                     \tl_set:Nx \l_colour_AC_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
                     \tl_set:Nx \l_colour_AD_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2} }
                    }
                   \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #1 } = 3 } }
                    {
                     \tl_set:Nx \l_colour_AC_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
                     \tl_set:Nx \l_colour_AD_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2} }
                     \tl_set:Nx \l_colour_AE_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {3} }
                    }
                  },
 }
```

This is the code I own, I have minimized it as much as possible so that it is understood (in my original document there is also `tikzmkpd / config-B`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz,etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,calc,tikzmark}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcommand*{\TkM}[2]{\tikzmarknode{#1}{#2}} % short :)
\makeatletter
\def\@colon{:} % active : for expl3
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__define_numeric_keys:nnnnnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9
 {
  \keys_define:nn { tkmdraw/config-#1 }
   {
    yshift-#1C .tl_set:c = {l_yshift_#1C_tl}, yshift-#1C .initial:n = #2,
    yshift-#1D .tl_set:c = {l_yshift_#1D_tl}, yshift-#1D .initial:n = #3,
    yshift-#1E .tl_set:c = {l_yshift_#1E_tl}, yshift-#1E .initial:n = #4,
    distan-#1C .tl_set:c = {l_distan_#1C_tl}, distan-#1C .initial:n = #5,
    distan-#1D .tl_set:c = {l_distan_#1D_tl}, distan-#1D .initial:n = #6,
    distan-#1E .tl_set:c = {l_distan_#1E_tl}, distan-#1E .initial:n = #7,
    angles-#1C .tl_set:c = {l_angles_#1C_tl}, angles-#1C .initial:n = #8,
    angles-#1D .tl_set:c = {l_angles_#1D_tl}, angles-#1D .initial:n = #8,
    angles-#1E .tl_set:c = {l_angles_#1E_tl}, angles-#1E .initial:n = #8,
    anglee-#1C .tl_set:c = {l_anglee_#1C_tl}, anglee-#1C .initial:n = #9,
    anglee-#1D .tl_set:c = {l_anglee_#1D_tl}, anglee-#1D .initial:n = #9,
    anglee-#1E .tl_set:c = {l_anglee_#1E_tl}, anglee-#1E .initial:n = #9,
   }
}
\__define_numeric_keys:nnnnnnnnn{A}{1.7ex}{1.7ex}{1.7ex}{1ex}{2ex}{3ex}{60}{120}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__define_colour_keys:nnnn #1#2#3#4
 {
  \keys_define:nn { tkmdraw/config-#1 }
   {
    colour-#1C .tl_set:c = {l_colour_#1C_tl}, colour-#1C .initial:n = #2,
    colour-#1D .tl_set:c = {l_colour_#1D_tl}, colour-#1D .initial:n = #3,
    colour-#1E .tl_set:c = {l_colour_#1E_tl}, colour-#1E .initial:n = #4,
   }
 }
\__define_colour_keys:nnnn{A}{red}{green}{blue}

\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A }
 {
  yshift-A   .tl_set:c  = {l_yshift_A_tl},%
  yshift-A   .initial:n = 1.7ex,
  end-yshift .code:n    = \__testkeys:nnn{A}{yshift}{#1},
  angle-star .code:n    = \__testkeys:nnn{A}{angles}{#1},
  angle-end  .code:n    = \__testkeys:nnn{A}{anglee}{#1},
  distance   .code:n    = \__testkeys:nnn{A}{distan}{#1},
  color      .code:n    = \__testkeys:nnn{A}{colour}{#1},
 }

\tl_new:N \l_tmpc_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__testkeys:nnn #1#2#3
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { #3 }
  \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #3 } = 1 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
    \keys_set:nn { tkmdraw/config-#1 }
     { #2-#1C= \l_tmpa_tl, }
   }
  \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #3 } = 2 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2} }
    \keys_set:nn { tkmdraw/config-#1 }
     { #2-#1C= \l_tmpa_tl, #2-#1D= \l_tmpb_tl, }
   }
  \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #3 } = 3 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpc_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {3} }
    \keys_set:nn { tkmdraw/config-#1 }
    { #2-#1C= \l_tmpa_tl, #2-#1D= \l_tmpb_tl, #2-#1E= \l_tmpc_tl,}
   }
 }

% case 1: a(c+d)  A1(B1+B2)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_case_one:n
 {
  \draw[->,\use:c{l_colour_AC_tl}]
  ([yshift=\use:c{l_yshift_A_tl}]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A1})$)
   to[out=\use:c{l_angles_AC_tl},in=\use:c{l_anglee_AC_tl},distance=\use:c{l_distan_AC_tl}]
   ([yshift=\use:c{l_yshift_AC_tl}]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B1})$);
  \draw[->,\use:c{l_colour_AD_tl}] %,
  ([yshift=\use:c{l_yshift_A_tl}]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A1})$)
   to[out=\use:c{l_angles_AD_tl},in=\use:c{l_anglee_AD_tl},distance=\use:c{l_distan_AD_tl}]
   ([yshift=\use:c{l_yshift_AD_tl}]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B2})$);
 }
% case 2: a(c+d+e)  A1(B1+B2+B3)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_case_two:n
 {
  \_case_one:n
  \draw[->,\use:c{l_colour_AE_tl}]
  ([yshift=\use:c{l_yshift_A_tl}]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{A1})$)
   to[out=\use:c{l_angles_AE_tl},in=\use:c{l_anglee_AE_tl},distance=\use:c{l_distan_AE_tl}]
   ([yshift=\use:c{l_yshift_AE_tl}]$(pic ~ cs\@colon\csuse{B3})$);
 }

\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd }
 {
  config-A .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A } { #1 } },
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\tikzmkpd}{O{} m m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \IfNoValueF { #1 } { \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd }{ #1 } }
   \foreach \x [count=\n] in {#2} { \csxdef{A\n}{\x} }%  save in A<n>
   \foreach \y [count=\m] in {#3} { \csxdef{B\m}{\y} }%  save in B<m>
   \tikzset{>={Straight ~ Barb[length=1.5pt,round,bend]}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember ~ picture]%
     \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #2 } = 1 }   &&
                   \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #3 } = 2 } } { \_case_one:n }
     \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #2 } = 1 }   &&
                   \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n { #3 } = 3 } } { \_case_two:n }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{case 1}
$\TkM{A}{2a^2}(\TkM{B}{b}+\TkM{D}{3q})$%
\tikzmkpd[config-A={end-yshift={15pt,15pt},yshift-A=15pt,color={gray,red}}]{A}{B,D}
\section{case 2}
$\TkM{a1}{2p}\left(\TkM{b1}{3q}+\TkM{c1}{4r}+\TkM{d1}{1}\right)$
\tikzmkpd[config-A={color={gray,gray,gray},end-yshift={5pt,5pt,5pt}}]{a1}{b1,c1,d1}
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to solve it?....(my idea is to try to repeat similar code as little as possible)

Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a minimal example, there are ten different questions here! The code given below works. Following the request in [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495065/problem-passing-a-key-color-separated-by-commas-from-l3keys-to-tikz/495101?noredirect=1#comment1249877_495101), I have made more changes than strictly necessary in order to better adhere to LaTeX3 coding conventions (to the best of my knowledge).

Note that the `_private_` naming scheme in `\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }` is an invention of mine; I don't know if there is a standard naming scheme for such situations. I did this way because I believe the keys defined under this hierarchy are an implementation detail of your macros and shouldn't be used directly by “users”.

LaTeX3 coding conventions are presented in [expl3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf), [l3styleguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf) and at the beginning of [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf). The indentation style suggested there is a bit different from yours (in particular, it uses a basic offset of two spaces). But the code below is already fairly readable, so I let you decide for yourself whether you want to strictly follow the indentation guidelines too.

For functions, I used:

- a `\__tikzmkpd_` prefix for private ones;
- a `\tikzmkpd_` prefix for public ones (only `\tikzmkpd:nnn`, which I added as the programming-layer backend function corresponding to the user-layer `\tikzmkpd` command you had already defined).

This way, it is very easy to turn all this code into a package that will play well with the rest of the LaTeX ecosystem. Your `\_case_one:n` and `\_case_two:n` functions had an incorrect name for two reasons:

- the prefix;
- the `:n` suffix which indicated they were supposed to take an argument, whereas they actually don't.

I renamed these two functions to `\__tikzmkpd_case_one:` and `\__tikzmkpd_case_two:`, respectively.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, calc, tikzmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_define_numeric_keys:nnnnnnnnn
                      #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9
 {
  \keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
   {
    yshift-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_yshift_#1C_tl }, yshift-#1C .initial:n = {#2},
    yshift-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_yshift_#1D_tl }, yshift-#1D .initial:n = {#3},
    yshift-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_yshift_#1E_tl }, yshift-#1E .initial:n = {#4},
    distan-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_distan_#1C_tl }, distan-#1C .initial:n = {#5},
    distan-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_distan_#1D_tl }, distan-#1D .initial:n = {#6},
    distan-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_distan_#1E_tl }, distan-#1E .initial:n = {#7},
    angles-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_angles_#1C_tl }, angles-#1C .initial:n = {#8},
    angles-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_angles_#1D_tl }, angles-#1D .initial:n = {#8},
    angles-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_angles_#1E_tl }, angles-#1E .initial:n = {#8},
    anglee-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_anglee_#1C_tl }, anglee-#1C .initial:n = {#9},
    anglee-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_anglee_#1D_tl }, anglee-#1D .initial:n = {#9},
    anglee-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_anglee_#1E_tl }, anglee-#1E .initial:n = {#9},
   }
}

\__tikzmkpd_define_numeric_keys:nnnnnnnnn
 { A } { 1.7ex } { 1.7ex } { 1.7ex } { 1ex } { 2ex } { 3ex } { 60 } { 120 }
\__tikzmkpd_define_numeric_keys:nnnnnnnnn
 { B }{ -0.5ex }{ -0.5ex }{ -0.5ex } { 1ex } { 2ex } { 3ex } {-60 } {-120 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_define_colour_keys:nnnn #1#2#3#4
 {
  \keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
   {
    colour-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_colour_#1C_tl }, colour-#1C .initial:n = {#2},
    colour-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_colour_#1D_tl }, colour-#1D .initial:n = {#3},
    colour-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_colour_#1E_tl }, colour-#1E .initial:n = {#4},
   }
 }

\__tikzmkpd_define_colour_keys:nnnn { A } { red } { green } { blue }
\__tikzmkpd_define_colour_keys:nnnn { B } { red } { green } { blue }

\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A }
 {
  yshift-A   .tl_set:c  = { l_yshift_A_tl },
  yshift-A   .initial:n = { 1.7ex },
  end-yshift .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { yshift } {#1} },
  angle-star .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { angles } {#1} },
  angle-end  .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { anglee } {#1} },
  distance   .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { distan } {#1} },
  color      .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { colour } {#1} },
  raise      .meta:n    = { yshift-A = {#1}, end-yshift = {#1,#1,#1} },
 }

\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd / config-B }
 {
  yshift-B   .tl_set:c  = { l_yshift_B_tl },
  yshift-B   .initial:n = { -0.5ex },
  end-yshift .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { yshift } {#1} },
  angle-star .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { angles } {#1} },
  angle-end  .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { anglee } {#1} },
  distance   .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { distan } {#1} },
  color      .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { colour } {#1} },
  raise      .meta:n    = { yshift-B = {#1}, end-yshift = {#1,#1,#1} },
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__tikzmkpd_subs_i:nnn #1#2#3
 { \exp_not:n { #1-#2C = {#3} } }

\cs_new:Npn \__tikzmkpd_subs_ii:nnnn #1#2#3#4
 { \exp_not:n { #1-#2C= {#3}, #1-#2D= {#4} } }

\cs_new:Npn \__tikzmkpd_subs_iii:nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
 { \exp_not:n { #1-#2C= {#3}, #1-#2D= {#4}, #1-#2E= {#5} } }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__tikzmkpd_subs_i:nnn { nnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__tikzmkpd_subs_ii:nnnn { nnVV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__tikzmkpd_subs_iii:nnnnn { nnVVV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set:nn { nx }

\tl_new:N \l__tikzmkpd_tmp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn #1#2#3
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#3}
  \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 1 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
    \keys_set:nx
     { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
     { \__tikzmkpd_subs_i:nnV {#2} {#1} \l_tmpa_tl }
   }
  \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 2 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2} }
    \keys_set:nx
     { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
     { \__tikzmkpd_subs_ii:nnVV {#2} {#1} \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl }
   }
  \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 3 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__tikzmkpd_tmp_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {3} }
    \keys_set:nx
     { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
     { \__tikzmkpd_subs_iii:nnVVV {#2} {#1} \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl
                                  \l__tikzmkpd_tmp_tl }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__tikzmkpd_mycmd_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_store_node_names:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tikzmkpd_mycmd_seq {#2}
    \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__tikzmkpd_mycmd_seq
      {
        \tl_clear_new:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_#1##1_tl }
        \tl_set:cn { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_#1##1_tl } {##2}
      }
  }

% case 1: a(c+d)  A1(B1+B2)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_case_one:
 {
  \draw[->, \use:c{l_colour_AC_tl}]
   ($(\tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A1_tl }) + (0, \use:c{l_yshift_A_tl})$)
   to[out=\use:c{l_angles_AC_tl}, in=\use:c{l_anglee_AC_tl},
      distance=\use:c{l_distan_AC_tl}]
   ([yshift=\use:c{l_yshift_AC_tl}] \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B1_tl });
  \draw[->,\use:c{l_colour_AD_tl}]
   ($(\tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A1_tl }) + (0, \use:c{l_yshift_A_tl})$)
   to[out=\use:c{l_angles_AD_tl}, in=\use:c{l_anglee_AD_tl},
      distance=\use:c{l_distan_AD_tl}]
   ([yshift=\use:c{l_yshift_AD_tl}] \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B2_tl });
 }

% case 2: a(c+d+e)  A1(B1+B2+B3)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_case_two:
 {
  \__tikzmkpd_case_one:
  \draw[->, \use:c{l_colour_AE_tl}]
   ($(\tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A1_tl }) + (0, \use:c{l_yshift_A_tl})$)
   to[out=\use:c{l_angles_AE_tl}, in=\use:c{l_anglee_AE_tl},
      distance=\use:c{l_distan_AE_tl}]
   ([yshift=\use:c{l_yshift_AE_tl}] \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B3_tl });
 }

\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd }
 {
  config-A .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A } {#1} },
  config-B .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd / config-B } {#1} },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tikzmkpd:nnn #1#2#3
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd } {#1}
  \__tikzmkpd_store_node_names:nn {A} {#2}
  \__tikzmkpd_store_node_names:nn {B} {#3}
  \tikzset{>={Straight ~ Barb[length=1.5pt,round,bend]}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember ~ picture]
      \bool_if:nT
        {
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#2} = 1 } &&
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 2 }
        }
        { \__tikzmkpd_case_one: }
      \bool_if:nT
        {
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#2} = 1 } &&
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 3 }
        }
        { \__tikzmkpd_case_two: }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmkpd { O{} m m }
 {
  \tikzmkpd:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\TkM}[2]{\tikzmarknode{#1}{#2}} % short :)
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section{case 1}

$\TkM{A}{2a^2}(\TkM{B}{b}+\TkM{D}{3q})$%
\tikzmkpd[config-A={end-yshift={8pt,9pt}, yshift-A=8pt, color={gray,red}}]%
         {A}{B, D}

\section{case 2}

$\TkM{a1}{2p}\left(\TkM{b1}{3q}+\TkM{c1}{4r}+\TkM{d1}{1}\right)$%
\tikzmkpd[config-A={color={gray,gray,gray}, end-yshift={5pt,5pt,5pt}}]%
         {a1}{b1, c1, d1}

\end{document}
```

I tested the preceding code, it gives the screenshot below. At the end of the post, you'll find a variant with improvements from Pablo that deals with more cases of the distributive property of multiplication (cases “one” to “four” instead of just “one” and “two”). However, I can't completely validate that version myself, as it apparently relies on recent bug fixes or features of PGF/Ti*k*Z—too recent for the version I have here, which is `2019/02/02 v3.1.1`.

[image: Screenshot]

I believe you can make progress regarding your debugging methodology: had you tested the output of *every single function of yours*, you'd have done:

```latex
\tl_show:N \l_yshift_AC_tl
\tl_show:N \l_yshift_AD_tl
\tl_show:N \l_colour_AC_tl
\tl_show:N \l_colour_AD_tl
```

right after the `\keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd } {#1}` call, which would have shown that your `\__testkeys:nnn` (now called `\__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn`) was not working properly. The main problem there was that you were passing single tokens such as `\l_tmpa_tl` in arguments where you actually wanted their *value* (something equivalent to the result of expanding `\l_tmpa_tl` or `\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl`; see how I did). Also, more bracing was desirable in some places in case some parameter values were to contain commas. For instance, this:

```latex
\cs_new:Npn \__tikzmkpd_subs_i:nnn #1#2#3
 { #1-#2C = {#3}, }
```

is preferable to this:

```latex
\cs_new:Npn \__tikzmkpd_subs_i:nnn #1#2#3
 { #1-#2C= #3, }
```

in case `#3` were to contain commas. In fact, unless you plan to use macros in `#1`, `#2` or `#3`, the following is maybe preferable in order to avoid unwanted expansions (since we later use it inside an `x` argument), which is what I did above:

```latex
\cs_new:Npn \__tikzmkpd_subs_i:nnn #1#2#3
 { \exp_not:n { #1-#2C = {#3} } }
```

The other problem that prevented the code from working is that for nodes created with `\tikzmarknode`, the `pic cs` syntax you used doesn't work—at least in my setup. The good news is, this can be simplified a lot (see my changes to `\_case_one:n` and `\_case_two:n` [now renamed to `\__tikzmkpd_case_one:` and `\__tikzmkpd_case_two:`]).

Your question is so complex with all the parameters, the TikZ code mixed up with the `l3keys` code, that I fear no one is going to reuse my answer. :-( I don't criticize the use of `l3keys` for TikZ work (for one, I'm much more comfortable myself with `l3keys` than with `pgfkeys`), but in the interest of other users of this site, I think you should have isolated the parsing problem from the TikZ issue—as people [already told you](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494795/key-v-a-l-argument-separated-by-commas-in-xparse#comment1249121_494795).

Your LaTeX coding skills seem good; my main advice would be:

- Read a bit more documentation, in particular on the LaTeX3 naming conventions, expansion and variants (see the first chapters of [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf)).
- Whenever you face again a problem like that, use `\tracingmacros=1 \tracingonline=1\relax`, and if this isn't enough to understand what is happening, print the value of every “thing” that your functions prepare<sup>1</sup> (for each of your functions). For example, before even trying to typeset the `tikzpicture`, print all options and all parameters that you are going to use therein. This method would have helped you find the errors in your `\__testkeys:nnn` (now renamed to `\__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn`).

As promised, here is the expanded code with additions from Pablo:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, calc, tikzmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_define_numeric_keys:nnnnnnnnn
                      #1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8#9
 {
  \keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
   {
    yshift-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_yshift_#1C_tl }, yshift-#1C .initial:n = {#2},
    yshift-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_yshift_#1D_tl }, yshift-#1D .initial:n = {#3},
    yshift-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_yshift_#1E_tl }, yshift-#1E .initial:n = {#4},
    distan-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_distan_#1C_tl }, distan-#1C .initial:n = {#5},
    distan-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_distan_#1D_tl }, distan-#1D .initial:n = {#6},
    distan-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_distan_#1E_tl }, distan-#1E .initial:n = {#7},
    angles-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_angles_#1C_tl }, angles-#1C .initial:n = {#8},
    angles-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_angles_#1D_tl }, angles-#1D .initial:n = {#8},
    angles-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_angles_#1E_tl }, angles-#1E .initial:n = {#8},
    anglee-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_anglee_#1C_tl }, anglee-#1C .initial:n = {#9},
    anglee-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_anglee_#1D_tl }, anglee-#1D .initial:n = {#9},
    anglee-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_anglee_#1E_tl }, anglee-#1E .initial:n = {#9},
   }
}

\__tikzmkpd_define_numeric_keys:nnnnnnnnn
 { A } { 1.7ex } { 1.7ex } { 1.7ex } { 1ex } { 2ex } { 3ex } { 60 } { 120 }
\__tikzmkpd_define_numeric_keys:nnnnnnnnn
 { B }{ -0.5ex }{ -0.5ex }{ -0.5ex } { 1ex } { 2ex } { 3ex } {-60 } {-120 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_define_colour_keys:nnnn #1#2#3#4
 {
  \keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
   {
    colour-#1C .tl_set:c = { l_colour_#1C_tl }, colour-#1C .initial:n = {#2},
    colour-#1D .tl_set:c = { l_colour_#1D_tl }, colour-#1D .initial:n = {#3},
    colour-#1E .tl_set:c = { l_colour_#1E_tl }, colour-#1E .initial:n = {#4},
   }
 }

\__tikzmkpd_define_colour_keys:nnnn { A } { red } { green } { blue }
\__tikzmkpd_define_colour_keys:nnnn { B } { red } { green } { blue }

\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A }
 {
  yshift-A   .tl_set:c  = { l_yshift_A_tl },
  yshift-A   .initial:n = { 1.7ex },
  end-yshift .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { yshift } {#1} },
  angle-star .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { angles } {#1} },
  angle-end  .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { anglee } {#1} },
  distance   .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { distan } {#1} },
  color      .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { A } { colour } {#1} },
  raise      .meta:n    = { yshift-A = {#1}, end-yshift = {#1,#1,#1} },
 }

\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd / config-B }
 {
  yshift-B   .tl_set:c  = { l_yshift_B_tl },
  yshift-B   .initial:n = { -0.5ex },
  end-yshift .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { yshift } {#1} },
  angle-star .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { angles } {#1} },
  angle-end  .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { anglee } {#1} },
  distance   .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { distan } {#1} },
  color      .code:n    = { \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn { B } { colour } {#1} },
  raise      .meta:n    = { yshift-B = {#1}, end-yshift = {#1,#1,#1} },
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__tikzmkpd_subs_i:nnn #1#2#3
 { \exp_not:n { #1-#2C = {#3} } }

\cs_new:Npn \__tikzmkpd_subs_ii:nnnn #1#2#3#4
 { \exp_not:n { #1-#2C= {#3}, #1-#2D= {#4} } }

\cs_new:Npn \__tikzmkpd_subs_iii:nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
 { \exp_not:n { #1-#2C= {#3}, #1-#2D= {#4}, #1-#2E= {#5} } }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__tikzmkpd_subs_i:nnn { nnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__tikzmkpd_subs_ii:nnnn { nnVV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__tikzmkpd_subs_iii:nnnnn { nnVVV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \keys_set:nn { nx }

\tl_new:N \l__tikzmkpd_tmp_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_set_subkeys:nnn #1#2#3
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#3}
  \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 1 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
    \keys_set:nx
     { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
     { \__tikzmkpd_subs_i:nnV {#2} {#1} \l_tmpa_tl }
   }
  \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 2 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2} }
    \keys_set:nx
     { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
     { \__tikzmkpd_subs_ii:nnVV {#2} {#1} \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl }
   }
  \bool_if:nT { \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 3 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {1} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {2} }
    \tl_set:Nx \l__tikzmkpd_tmp_tl { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {3} }
    \keys_set:nx
     { tikzmkpd/_private_/config-#1 }
     { \__tikzmkpd_subs_iii:nnVVV {#2} {#1} \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl
                                  \l__tikzmkpd_tmp_tl }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__tikzmkpd_mycmd_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_store_node_names:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__tikzmkpd_mycmd_seq {#2}
    \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__tikzmkpd_mycmd_seq
      {
        \tl_clear_new:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_#1##1_tl }
        \tl_set:cn { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_#1##1_tl } {##2}
      }
  }

% case 1: a(c+d)  A1(B1+B2)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_case_one:
 {
  \draw[->, \tl_use:c{l_colour_AC_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_A_tl}]$(pic ~ cs  \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A1_tl})$)
   to[out=\tl_use:c{l_angles_AC_tl}, in=\tl_use:c{l_anglee_AC_tl},
      distance=\tl_use:c{l_distan_AC_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_AC_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B1_tl})$);
  \draw[->,\tl_use:c{l_colour_AD_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_A_tl}]$(pic ~ cs  \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A1_tl})$)
   to[out=\tl_use:c{l_angles_AD_tl}, in=\tl_use:c{l_anglee_AD_tl},
      distance=\tl_use:c{l_distan_AD_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_AD_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B2_tl})$);
 }

% case 2: a(c+d+e)  A1(B1+B2+B3)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_case_two:
 {
  \__tikzmkpd_case_one:
  \draw[->, \tl_use:c{l_colour_AE_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_A_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A1_tl})$)
   to[out=\tl_use:c{l_angles_AE_tl}, in=\tl_use:c{l_anglee_AE_tl},
      distance=\tl_use:c{l_distan_AE_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_AE_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B3_tl})$);
 }

% case 3: (a+b)(c+d) (A1+A2)(B1+B2)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_case_three:
 {
  \__tikzmkpd_case_one:
  \draw[->,\tl_use:c{l_colour_BC_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_B_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A2_tl})$)
   to[out=\tl_use:c{l_angles_BC_tl},in=\tl_use:c{l_anglee_BC_tl},
      distance=\tl_use:c{l_distan_BC_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_BC_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B1_tl})$);
  \draw[->,\tl_use:c{l_colour_BD_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_B_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : }  \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A2_tl})$)
   to[out=\tl_use:c{l_angles_BD_tl},in=\tl_use:c{l_anglee_BD_tl},
      distance=\tl_use:c{l_distan_BD_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_BD_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B2_tl})$);
 }

% case 4: (a+b)(c+d+e) (A1+A2)(B1+B2+B3)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_case_four:
 {
  \__tikzmkpd_case_three:
  \draw[->,\tl_use:c{l_colour_AE_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_A_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : }  \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A1_tl})$)
   to[out=\tl_use:c{l_angles_AE_tl},in=\tl_use:c{l_anglee_AE_tl},
      distance=\tl_use:c{l_distan_AE_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_AE_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B3_tl})$);
  \draw[->,\tl_use:c{l_colour_BE_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_B_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : }  \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_A2_tl})$)
   to[out=\tl_use:c{l_angles_BE_tl},in=\tl_use:c{l_anglee_BE_tl},
      distance=\tl_use:c{l_distan_BE_tl}]
   ([yshift=\tl_use:c{l_yshift_BE_tl}]$(pic ~ cs \tl_to_str:n { : } \tl_use:c { l__tikzmkpd_nodename_B3_tl})$);
 }

\keys_define:nn { tikzmkpd }
 {
  config-A .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd / config-A } {#1} },
  config-B .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd / config-B } {#1} },
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \tikzmkpd:nnn #1#2#3
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { tikzmkpd } {#1}
  \__tikzmkpd_store_node_names:nn {A} {#2}
  \__tikzmkpd_store_node_names:nn {B} {#3}
  \tikzset{>={Straight ~ Barb[length=1.5pt,round,bend]}}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember ~ picture]
      \bool_if:nT
        {
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#2} = 1 } &&
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 2 }
        }
        { \__tikzmkpd_case_one: }
      \bool_if:nT
        {
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#2} = 1 } &&
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 3 }
        }
        { \__tikzmkpd_case_two: }
      \bool_if:nT
        {
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#2} = 2 } &&
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 2 }
        }
        { \__tikzmkpd_case_three: }
      \bool_if:nT
        {
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#2} = 2 }   &&
          \int_compare_p:n { \clist_count:n {#3} = 3 }
        }
        { \__tikzmkpd_case_four: }
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \tikzmkpd { O{} m m }
 {
  \tikzmkpd:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*{\TkM}[2]{\tikzmarknode{#1}{#2}} % short :)
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\section{case 1}

$\TkM{A}{2a^2}(\TkM{B}{b}+\TkM{D}{3q})$%
\tikzmkpd[config-A={raise=12pt}]%
         {A}{B, D}

\section{case 2}

$\TkM{a1}{2p}\left(\TkM{b1}{3q}+\TkM{c1}{4r}+\TkM{d1}{1}\right)$%
\tikzmkpd[config-A={color={gray,gray,gray}, end-yshift={5pt,5pt,5pt}}]%
         {a1}{b1, c1, d1}

\section{case 3}

$(\TkM{X1}{2a^2}+\TkM{X2}{n})(\TkM{Y1}{b}+\TkM{Y2}{3q})$%
\tikzmkpd{X1,X2}{Y1,Y2}

\section{case 4}

$(\TkM{a}{x}-\TkM{b}{2})(\TkM{c}{x^2}+\TkM{d}{2x}+\TkM{e}{4})$
\tikzmkpd[config-B={end-yshift={-15pt,-15pt},color={gray,red}}]{a,b}{c, d, e}

\tikzmkpd[config-A={raise=4pt,color={gray,gray,gray}}]%
         {A}{B, D}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Footnote**

1. For such temporary code, you can use TeX or LaTeX2e commands such as `\show` or `\typeout`, as well as LaTeX3 ones such as `\tl_show:N` or `\box_show:N`.

Comment: Great, can you modify your response to fit LaTeX3 naming conventions, I'll adapt the rest of my code (including `config-B`). Related to `(pic cs)`, in my case it works well, the problem is in `tikzmark` (https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/issues/9) in my case I have installed the version from `git`.   And it's true, mixing `pgfkeys` with `l3key` doesn't seem like a good idea, but, I just want to modify those parameters and not the rest of the `tikz` options, so from my point of view it's fine. I must study more about the use of variants and expansion in `expl3`. Gracias Totales :)

Comment: Please see my last edits. As said there, I don't criticize the use of `l3keys` for TikZ work; what I'm saying is that you could have completely separated the parsing issue from the TikZ one as part of reducing your example to something minimal. And probably you would have found the problem yourself while doing so, because you would likely have seen then what was happening when preparing the options destined to TikZ.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I tried to separate and reduce a little the code, but, I do not remain as a MWE (thousand apologies). Debugging the keys and code using `\debug_on:n { check-declarations , deprecation }` and `\tl_show:N` along with a more accurate reading of the `expl3` documentation should have been my starting point. The `yshift-A` key doesn't work, I'll add the use of `(pic cs)` and this solves my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: I've fixed `yshift-A` too. It was a TikZ parsing (syntax) problem—don't ask me why the other quite similar cases work. As can be seen with `\tl_show:N`, `\l_yshift_A_tl` was quite fine in `\__tikzmkpd_case_one:` and `\__tikzmkpd_case_two:` even before [this edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/495101/revisions) (i.e., all the LaTeX3 option parsing code was working as designed).

Comment: Now everything is going great....In my first attempt I had left `yshift-A` inside `\__tikzmkpd_define_numeric` and also failed, `TikZ` is a bit dark and difficult to understand in certain points. Until next time and thank you for the programming lesson and debug in `LaTeX|expl3`.

Comment: Hi, I could update your response by removing the dependency of the `etoolbox` package for the use of `\seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn` from the response given by @egreg at (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496604/7832), just with the idea of having one more code in the `expl3` line. Saludos

Comment: Hi, I'm not against `\seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn` in principle, but I don't remember introducing the dependency on `etoolbox` myself here. I see it's used for `\csxdef` (which could be replaced by `expl3` stuff but not by `\seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn`), however this command was in your original code, it's not from me either. What else is there that you'd like to convert? Can you post the new file somewhere, or a diff for instance on https://pastebin.com (or an additional answer you'll cancel, I don't know...)? Thanks.

Comment: Ah right, I think I see what you mean, this *is* around the `\csxdef` (sorry, there was some disturbance around...). It seems okay to me in principle.

Comment: I have added the modifications, I published them in temporary code at the beginning of the post, of course, they are better in their response for the rest of the users who review the forum :)...if you have some time you can give me a hand with (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497079/7832). Gracias

Comment: I'm going to review it (for the other link, we'll see...). There are a few problems: 1) Already existing: I forgot to add braces around several of your `:n` values in the key definitions. 2) Private function names (`\__tikzmkpd_pass_comma_args:nn`) start with two underscores after the backslash. 3) `\l__tikzmkpd_mycmd_seq` wasn't declared. I'll fix these and see the rest, no need to fix them on your side.

Comment: Also, `l_tikzmkpd_#1##1_tl` means the variable is public (and local), is it what you intended? Otherwise, use `l__tikzmkpd_#1##1_tl`. And I would add something else (fixed string) to the name to avoid any clash with the other cs names in case of particular user input.

Comment: A thousand apologies, it was a quick adaptation and I still get lost with the use of `_` and `__`.

Comment: Private (for functions as well as variables) is always with two consecutive underscores. For `l_tikzmkpd_#1##1_tl`, search&replace on `l_tikzmkpd_` seems safe. To avoid clashes (as said) and declare it as private, I propose the name `l__tikzmkpd_nodename_#1##1_tl`. What do you think?

Comment: Nice, `l__tikzmkpd_nodename_#1##1_tl` is much more natural for me :)

Comment: Okay, please see the last edit. I renamed a few more things. I can't completely validate your code because of the `pic cs` problem, but since you say it is fixed in PGF/Ti*k*Z Git, I have included yours at the end of the post, with my fixes applied. You can retest it and add a screenshot if you want (at the end, right after the code). I can compile your version but the rendering is not correct, so no screenshot. I included as much as I could in my version, though, so the only differences are in the TikZ code and the new cases, “three” and “four” (+ settings in the first tests that would...

Comment: ...  render my screenshot invalid).

Comment: Great, I added an image of the result, ....you know, in my updated distribution, I compile it without problems (and without using the git version of `tikzmark`). Grateful for your time :)

Comment: All right, you're welcome. I've added your screenshot, but you could have done the same via an edit. :) For the other little formatting fixes I did, there was stuff like `{ #2 }` → `{#2}` and `\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_store_node_names:nn #1 #2` → `\cs_new_protected:Npn \__tikzmkpd_store_node_names:nn #1#2` (spaces removed). These are from the recommendations in [l3styleguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf).

Comment: Oops, you're right, now that I read the title of my question right, it looks more like an "XY problem." Do you have a better idea for the title of the question?

Comment: “XY problem” isn't very clear to me... Maybe something like “Recursive use of `l3keys`: `key1 = {subkey1=value1, subkey2=value2, ...}, ...`” (note: backquotes don't “work” in titles, AFAIK). BTW, I suppose that renaming the question would break the link one can find on [your board](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7832/pablo-gonz%c3%a1lez-l) (I know one can have a [permalink for the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495065/73317), though...).

Comment: (or maybe TeX.SE keeps the link with the old title as an alias, I don't know).

Comment: I think the current version of the forum updates the links...I better leave it like this:)

Comment: This could be a question for [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) (whether the old link is kept as an alias). :-) (maybe it has already been asked...)

Comment: Hi, I saw your answer on (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530808/7832) and I have a question related to this (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565026/7832), you can give me a hand here :-)